# iPhone Movie Rotation For Only Subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working on an app that disallows rotation unless a movie is playing.  I have the app rotated just fine, but the issue comes about when I try to view the movie.

The simulator is forced to rotate, but the movie does not.  An example of this is below:

[image: Movie Player Error]

I can't figure out how to rotate the movie too. I am looking to rotate only the subview. My code is below:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalURL]];
if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
                // Use the 3.2 style API  
                moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;  
                moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
                [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  
                [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

             // Rotate the view for landscape playback
             [[moviePlayer view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
             [[moviePlayer view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
             [[moviePlayer view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)]; 

             // Set frame of movieplayer
             [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];  

            } else {  
                // Use the 2.0 style API  
                moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;  
                [moviePlayer play];  
            } 
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried `[moviePlayer setOrientation UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];` but the complier gives me an error and nothing happens

Comment: have you tested on a real device?

Comment: Yes, and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Try the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. That class is a UIViewController and should handle the rotation on it self.

You get the MPMoviePlayerController from the view controller by just calling the method `[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer];`

Comment: I am, I just forgot to add it to the question.  It is there now.